# include imported functions in module documentation

Tags: python, documentation

My code has the following directory structure:

```
apkg/
  __init__.py
  amod.py
  bmod.py
  cmod.py
```

Where `apkg/__init__.py` contains:

```
"""
effusive top-level documentation
"""
from apkg.amod import foo
from apkg.bmod import bar
from apkg.cmod import baz
```

And from the python repl I can successfully invoke `foo`, `bar`, and `baz` without knowing which submodule they're defined in:

```
>>> import apkg
>>> apkg.foo()
"foo"
```

And get their documentation:

```
>>> help(apkg.foo)
Help on function foo in module apkg.amod:

foo()
    Returns "foo"
```

But they're not advertised in `apkg`'s documentation:

```
>>> help(apkg)
Help on package apkg:

NAME
    apkg - effusive top-level documentation

PACKAGE CONTENTS
    amod
    bmod
    cmod

FILE
    /path/to/apkg/__init__.py
```

This makes sense as a default, since I'd hardly want to include `defaultdict`'s documentation just by doing `from collections import defaultdict` in `apkg/__init__.py`.

Is there a way to override this default, so I can tell the documentation parser to list `foo`, `bar` and `baz` in the FUNCTIONS section for `help(apkg)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834/can-someone-explain-all-in-python/35710527#35710527):

> #### Documentation tools
>
> Documentation and code autocompletion tools may (in fact, should) also inspect the `__all__` to determine what names to show as available from a module.

So it's as simple as appending a single line to `apkg/__init__.py`

```
__all__ = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
```